# Managing connection with non-buffered queries in Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dapper, micro-orm

I have recently started using [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net), everything seems nice and easy but there is one thing that keeps confusing me: Connection Management.

As per the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/#Limitations_and_caveats):

> Dapper does not manage your connection's lifecycle, it assumes the
>   connection it gets is open AND has no existing datareaders enumerating
>   (unless MARS is enabled)

In light of this I started doing this inside the implementation of my repository methods:

```
using (var db = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)) {
    // call Dapper methods here
}
```

Then I came across a table with a large number of records, so I though of returning an `IEnumerable<T>` by passing `buffered: false` to the `Query<>` method, and when I started enumerating the enumerable in the front end, boom an exception saying the connection was closed and disposed which is expected since I am wrapping my calls with the preceding using block.

**Question:** Best way to solve this ?
**Side question:** Is the way I am managing the connection the preferred way to go about it ?

Comment: Just in case this helps someone else, I used buffered: false and it corrected my connection issue w/ dapper.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd offer this repository pattern:

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected T GetConnection<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> getData)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return getData(connection);
        }
    }

    protected TResult GetConnection<TRead, TResult>(Func<IDbConnection, TRead> getData, Func<TRead, TResult> process)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var data = getData(connection);
            return process(data);
        }
    }
}
```

For buffered queries you want to use first overload of `GetConnection` method, for non-buffered you use second, specifing callback for processing data:

```
public class MyRepository : Repository
{
    public MyRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyMapObject> GetData()
    {
        return GetConnection(c => c.Query<MyMapObject>(query));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResultObject> GetLotsOfData(Func<IEnumerable<MyMapObject>, IEnumerable<ResultObject>> process)
    {
        return GetConnection(c => c.Query<MyMapObject>(query, buffered: false), process);
    }
}
```

Very basic usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var repository = new MyRepository(connectionString);
    var data = repository.GetLotsOfData(ProcessData);
}

public static IEnumerable<ResultObject> ProcessData(IEnumerable<MyMapObject> data)
{
    foreach (var record in data)
    {
        var result = new ResultObject();
        //do some work...
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind - connection may be opened for too long time in this case...

Comment: Ohh man, what was I thinking. Thank you Sergio for reminding me of that `yield` keyword. I don't know why I forgot about its usage. One thing though, You don't need all of this plumbing to get this working, you can just use `yield return result` inside the method implementation in the repository directly. If no one else came with a better answer I will award you the bounty. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, the connection doesn't need to be open in the newer version of Dapper. SqlMapper class checks the state of the connection and if it's closed, it will call `Open()` on it.

Answer (score 7):

@Sergio, AWESOME! Thanks for such a great pattern. I modified it slightly to be async so that I can use it with Dapper's async methods. Makes my entire request chain async, from the controllers all the way back to the DB! Gorgeous!

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    private readonly string _ConnectionString;

    protected BaseRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    // use for buffered queries
    protected async Task<T> WithConnection<T>(Func<IDbConnection, Task<T>> getData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                return await getData(connection);
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL timeout", GetType().FullName), ex);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL exception (not a timeout)", GetType().FullName), ex);
        }
    }

    // use for non-buffeed queries
    protected async Task<TResult> WithConnection<TRead, TResult>(Func<IDbConnection, Task<TRead>> getData, Func<TRead, Task<TResult>> process)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var data = await getData(connection);
                return await process(data);
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL timeout", GetType().FullName), ex);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL exception (not a timeout)", GetType().FullName), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Use with Dapper like this:

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public PersonRepository(string connectionString): base (connectionString) { }

    // Assumes you have a Person table in your DB that 
    // aligns with a Person POCO model.
    //
    // Assumes you have an existing SQL sproc in your DB 
    // with @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as a parameter. The sproc 
    // returns rows from the Person table.
    public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
    {
        return await WithConnection(async c =>
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("Id", Id, DbType.Guid);
            var people = await c.QueryAsync<Person>(sql: "sp_Person_GetById", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return people.FirstOrDefault();
        });
    }
}
```